# sklearn/PCA - Error while trying to transform the high dimentional data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pca

I encountered data error while trying to convert my high dimensional vector into 2 dimension using PCA.

This is my input `data`, each row has 300 dimensions:

```
                                                  vector
0      [0.01053525, -0.007869658, 0.0024931028, -0.04...
1      [-0.024436072, -0.016484523, 0.03859031, 0.000...
2      [0.015011676, -0.020465894, 0.004854744, -0.00...
3      [-0.010836455, -0.006562917, 0.00265073, 0.022...
4      [-0.018123362, -0.026007563, 0.04781856, -0.03...
...                                                  ...
45124  [-0.016111804, -0.041917775, 0.010192914, -0.0...
45125  [0.0311568, -0.013044083, 0.030656694, -0.0126...
45126  [-0.021875003, -0.005635035, 0.0076896898, -0....
45127  [-0.0062000924, -0.041035958, 0.0077403532, 0....
45128  [0.007794927, 0.0019561667, 0.15995999, -0.054...

[45129 rows x 1 columns]
```

My Code:

```
data = pd.read_parquet('1.parquet', engine='fastparquet')

reduced = pca.fit_transform(data)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8e547411a212> in <module>
----> 1 reduced = pca.fit_transform(data)
...
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**Edit**

```
>>data.shape
(45129, 1)
>>data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 45129 entries, 0 to 45128
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   vector  45129 non-null  object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 352.7+ KB
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `data.shape`? You say the data has 300 columns but the code above says `[45129 rows x 1 columns]` which suggests something is wrong with how you've read the parquet file

Comment: @mbatchkarov added. Thanks!

Comment: @mbatchkarov The parquet file is correct. It is the output from word2vec. Each row vector represents a word. Something like vector ```[0.01, 0.02, 0.03]```(3 dimensional in this case) representing ```hello``` for example.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with how you read the parquet file, but the data frame clearly has only one column. The input file must be wrong, can you upload it here if it's not confidential? How did you write this file?

Comment: @mbatchkarov As I mentioned above, the parquet file is from word2vec. It indeed has 1 column only. What I want to do is to reduce the 300 dimensional data in this single column into 2 dimension.

Comment: @mbatchkarov the parquet file was created via ```model.save``` in the spark ml lib for word2vec. I wanted to visualise my vectorised text so I attempted to use PCA+matplotlib to do that.

Comment: "It indeed has 1 column only [...] to reduce the 300 dimensional data" If your data has one column, you have 1-dimensional data, not 300. You need to reshape it like @Nick Becker suggests

Comment: @mbatchkarov Exactly. Nick's solution worked for me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikit-learn doesn't know how to handle a column that contains an array (list), so you'll need to expand the column. Since each row has an array of the same size, you can do this fairly easily with only 45,000 rows. Once you expand your data, you should be fine.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
​
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [[0.01, 0.02, 0.03], [0.04, 0.4, 0.1]]})
expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(df.a.tolist())
expanded_df
0   1   2
0   0.01    0.02    0.03
1   0.04    0.40    0.10
```

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
reduced = pca.fit_transform(expanded_df)
reduced
array([[ 1.93778224e-01,  1.43048962e-17],
       [-1.93778224e-01,  1.43048962e-17]])
```